# Supremum and infimum of $S = \left\{\frac{n-1}{n+1} \cdot\cos\left(\frac{2n \pi}{3}\right) : n \in \Bbb N\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let us consider the set $$S = \left\{\frac{n-1}{n+1} \cdot\cos\left(\frac{2n \pi}{3}\right) : n \in \Bbb N\right\}$$
I am trying to find the supremum and infimum of the set.

We know that $\cos\frac{2n \pi}{3}$ is either $-\frac12$ or $1$. Also we can write $$\frac{n-1}{n+1} = 1 - \frac{2}{n+1}$$

I am not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let
$$f(n) = \frac{n-1}{n+1} \cos\left( \frac{2n\pi}{3}\right).$$
Then,
$$f(3n) = \frac{3n-1}{3n+1} \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ f(3n+1) = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{(3n-1) -1}{(3n+1)+1}.$$
Hence, as $n\to\infty$, the sequences $f(3n)$ and $f(3n+1)$ converge to limits (which are...?). Then note that
$$ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{n-1}{n+1} \le f(n) \le \frac{n-1}{n+1}$$
because, as you observed, $\cos(2n\pi/3)$ is either $-1/2$ or $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe \begin{align} S&= \left\{\frac{3k-1}{3k+1}\cos\left(\frac{3k\cdot 2\pi}3\right),\frac{3k-1-1}{3k-1+1}\cos\left(\frac{(3k-1)\cdot2\pi}3\right),\frac{3k-2-1}{3k-2+1}\cos\left(\frac{(3k-2)\cdot2\pi}3\right);k\in\mathbb N\right\}\\&=\left\{\frac{3k-1}{3k+1},-\frac12\cdot\frac{3k-2}{3k},-\frac12\cdot\frac{3k-3}{3k-1};k\in\mathbb N\right\}.\tag 1\label 1\end{align}

It only suffices to check for $3k, ~3k-1, ~3k-2$ (why?). It is now easy to conclude from $\eqref 1$ that $\sup S=1, ~\inf S=-\frac12.$